# Why is $\Delta(f)(s,t)= f(st)$ well-defined?

Tags: measure-theory, topological-groups, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a locally compact group with Haar measure $\lambda$. The locally compact group $G\times G$ then carries the Haar measure $\lambda\times \lambda$. One can then define the map
$$\Delta: L^\infty(G)\to L^\infty(G\times G, \lambda\times \lambda)$$
by
$$\Delta(f)(s,t) = f(st).$$
Why is this well-defined? I.e. if $f= 0$ almost everywhere, why is $\Delta(f)= 0$ almost everywhere? This seems to be well-known, but not so obvious to me: Why is
$$\{(s,t): f(st)\ne 0\}$$
a null-set, if $\{f\ne 0\}$ is a null-set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote $\cdot : G\times G \to G$ to be the group operation. We will think about it as function from product to $G$ most of the times.
For $f \in L^\infty(G, \lambda)$, the function $\Delta f$ is composition $f \circ \cdot$. You are essentially asking why
$$\lambda(f^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\})) = 0\quad\implies\quad \lambda \times \lambda ((f \circ \cdot)^{-1} (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\})) = 0.$$

This can be proven using the defining property of product measure, and invariance of Haar measure with respect to $\cdot$. Product measure is one satisfying
$$
\lambda \times \lambda(A) = \int_G \lambda(A^g) \lambda(dg),$$
where $A \subseteq G\times G$ and $A^g = \{h \in G: (g, h) \in A\}$.
With that, we can write for any $\lambda$-null set $Z \subseteq G$ that
$$
\lambda \times \lambda(\cdot^{-1} Z)
= \int_G \lambda((\cdot^{-1} Z)^g) \lambda(dg)
= \int_G \lambda(g^{-1}Z)) \lambda(dg),
$$
because $(\cdot^{-1} Z)^g = \{h: g \cdot h \in Z\}$. Now using invariance, function under the integral is always $\lambda(Z) = 0$, and therefore integral is zero as well.

The result now follows by taking $Z = \{g: f(g) \neq 0\}$, because $\cdot^{-1} Z$ is then precisely $\{(g, h): f(gh) \neq 0\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There are technicalities here: you use properties of product measures that are no longer true if the group $G$ is not $\sigma$-compact. Even if Haar measure is not $\sigma$-finite, we can make sense of $\lambda\times \lambda$, but the formulas you mention don't work anymore in general I think.

Comment: I still accepted this answer because it is sufficient for the case I was interested in.